Jupyter Notebook not running | Python path incorrect
I'm trying to access jupyter notebook but I'm getting weird path of python package that must be used

C:\Windows\System32>where python
C:\Windows\python.exe
C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Windows\System32>where jupyter
C:\Users\abcd\Scripts\jupyter.exe

C:\Windows\System32>jupyter
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\abcd\python.exe"  "C:\Users\abcd\Scripts\jupyter.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.


I have C:\Windows and C:\Users\abcd\Scripts in environment variables for system and user and there's no python installed at c:\users\abcd\python.exe nor it is anywhere in path variables, i've tried everything I could restarting and redefining path variables but nothing worked.
Any help would be much appreciated.
PS: python was previously installed at C:\users\abcd\python.exe but is removed completely from system via uninstallation and deletion of files. Also why its c: and not C: in error.
